# Can not CREATE USER in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, powershell, command-prompt, ubuntu-20.04

I tried on powershell, command prompt, and ubuntu for windows:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER sally WITH PASSWORD 'secret';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 sally     |                                                            | {}
postgres=# \q
> psql -U sally
Password for user sally:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sally"
```

Also if I write `psql` or `$ sudo su - postgres` (in ubuntu)

It would ask me for my Windows USERNAME (respectfuly):

`Password for user xyz:`

`[sudo] password for xyz:`

Here's my `pg_hba.conf`

```
...
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
...
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add `-h 127.0.0.1` when connecting, or add a `local` rule to `pg_hba.conf`.

Also, specify the wanted DB name if it's not the same as the user name: `-d <dbname>`.

Comment: I don't know why my computer is so weird, it does connect to DATABASE, only after I login into 'postgres' and `create database sally` (same username and database):`sally=>`, and also I tested if i `create database mydb` it gives me again `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mydb"`

Comment: I also noticed **before creating database with owner sally** if i Try to connect as `psql -U sally -h 127.0.0.1` I get = `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "sally" does not exist`
Why it's seeking database, when I 1. Create USER, 2. Try to connect to USER?

Comment: Specify the DB name while connecting, otherwise psql will be looking for a DB with the same name as the user. It's probably `postgres`, so add `-d postgres` or just `postgres` at the end of the command.